# UITableView "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method gets called twice on a swipe abruptly

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-4.2

I think many of us has faced this problem on `UITableView` delegate method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which gets called twice.

In my application I transforming the tableView. The code is:

```
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
theTableView.transform = transform;
    
    theTableView.rowHeight = self.bounds.size.width;

    theTableView.frame = self.bounds;
```

Now inside the delegate method I am doing a couple of things:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{        
    
    modelRef.currentCellAtIndexPathRow = indexPath.row;
    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier frame:self.bounds] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    
                
    modelRef.currentPageIndex = (indexPath.row + 1);
    
    [cell showPage];

    NSLog(@" visible cell %i ",[[tableView visibleCells] count]);

        
    return cell;
}
```

At a time 1 cell is visible, but first time when the application launches. The log shows visible cells 0.

Many a times this particular delegate method gets called twice abruptly.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think an immediate fix is just to set a flag which changes the first time it is hit, so then you ignore the second call. It's probably not the perfect solution, and I can't tell you why it gets hit twice - but this will work. (I have experienced exactly the same behavior when I implemented an Apple delegate from the `UIWebView` class)

EDIT:

Create a `BOOL` member in the class header, then in the init set the value to be `YES`. So if the `BOOL` is called `mbIsFirstCall` for example, in your delegate method, do the following:

```
if (mbIsFirstCall)
{
    // do your processing, then the line below
    mbIsFirstCall = NO;
}
else
{
    // you don't need this else, but just for clarity it is here.
    // you should only end up inside here when this method is hit the second time, so we ignore it.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can u pls give a sample of code exactly what you mean?

Comment: Thanks again. I tried this earlier. In this scenario, on first swipe,mbIsFirstCall will set to NO. This is one time check I think, is the variable changes to YES anytime? Otherwise on each time else statement will be met. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @iWasRobot If you're happy with the answer, remember to vote up or accept it. :) Glad it has worked out for you!